# Is it possible to migrate unit tests using BlockJUnit4ClassRunner to Junit 5?

Tags: amazon-web-services, junit5, amazon-swf

I'm migrating to Junit 5 and I'm blocked by tests running with `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` and `WorkflowTest`. Has anyone done anything similar? I can't find in the amazon documentation anything related to JUnit 5

Edit: This is currently used as per the amazon documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/test.html#test.junit

Answer (score 1):

The runner mechanism is no longer present in JUnit 5. It’s been replaced by Jupiter extensions or in some cases by test engines. To give advice on how a migration could be done in your specific case you must give a full example of how BlockJUnit4ClassRunner is being applied in your code.

Comment: This is exactly how it is used in the existing code. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/test.html#test.junit. I am not sure there is actually a way to migrate this to JUnit 5 without having to rewrite the library.

Comment: AwsFlow tests use both a specialised runner and a rule. There’s probably no easy way to migrate that to JUnit 5 Jupiter without intimate knowledge about the framework itself. You should contact the framework maintainers about upgrading to JUnit 5. What JUnit 5 allows to do is having tests for different versions in the same project. Thus you can use JUnit 4 (vintage) for these workflow tests and Jupiter for the rest.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I have at the moment. Vintage running a few tests and Junit5 running the lot. I was just hoping to clean up everything and have only one style of tests.